# Duplicate dates in xts object lead to wrong indexing

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have data with users and duplicated dates e.g. users accessing a web site.
Example:

```
require(zoo)
require(xts)

test <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2013-03-06 01:00:00", "2014-07-06 21:00:00", 
                                  "2014-07-31 23:00:00", "2014-08-09 17:00:00", "2014-08-14 20:00:00", 
                                  "2014-08-14 22:00:00", "2014-08-16 15:00:00", "2014-08-19 02:00:00", 
                                  "2014-12-28 18:00:00", "2015-01-17 17:00:00"), user = c(1, 2, 
                                                                                          2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)), .Names = c("timestamp", "user"), row.names = c("220667", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "331481", "422653", "629430", "378111", "646137", "558638", "151641", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "599370", "482750"), class = "data.frame")
```

If I create an xts object and then access it with its own index I get different data. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
testXts <- xts(x=test,order.by = as.Date(test$timestamp))
testXts[index(testXts)]#Different (wrong) data. Why ?
```

Comment: What different data? What do you see that you are not expecting? I'm guessing you need to use `xts(x=test[, -1],order.by = as.Date(test$timestamp))` so you drop the timestamp column from the matrix. Otherwise your xts matrix will be a character value

Comment: I omitted the timestamp column and get the same problem. The row with time stamp 2014-07-06 21:00:00  and user  2 ist still missing after testXts[index(testXts)].

Comment: @phiver: the issue is still there if you omit the timestamp from the coredata. Seems like a bug, and I checked that exists in the development version of xts.

Comment: @Joshua-Ulrich I am currently really busy in a software project and I never filed a bug report before. I will do it next week or later. If it is necessary to file it sooner, it is OK if you file it and get the credit for it.

Comment: No worries, I created [issue #275](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/275) so this doesn't get forgotten.